# How does multiple arrow functions work in es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, currying, arrow-functions

I have to review one of react script that initially create by company's outsourcing. I accidentally fall in to this block of code and confuse about the multiple arrow function. The block of code is look like this

```
export const createSectionCreator = getQuestions => (
  id,
  label,
  styleOptions,
  heading
) => (app, prefix) => ({
  id,
  label,
  heading,
  questions: getQuestions(app, prefix, { id, label }),
  styleOptions: _.defaults(styleOptions, {})
})
```

I know that how below code is worked 
    let sum = x => y => x+y

But I don't understand how the original code is worked

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/

Comment: What do you mean by "how the original code is worked"?

Comment: @devserkan He wants to understand how this is working.

Comment: Read [Currying versus partial application (with JavaScript code)](http://2ality.com/2011/09/currying-vs-part-eval.html) article. You will be set after reading it. And this [Currying](http://2ality.com/2017/11/currying-in-js.html#currying).

Comment: @ArupRakshit, but OP says "I know that how below code is worked". I think, I misunderstood :)

Comment: Looks like this is really just about function currying. To my understanding, `createSectionCreator` is a function that accepts parameter `getQuestions` as parameter, then returns a function that accepts `id, label, styleOptions, heading`, then it returns a function which accepts `app, prefix` parameter which ultimately returns a JSON object containing `id, label, heading, questions, styleOptions`.

Comment: The parentheses just define multiple parameter names per nested functions. Like `let sum = x => (y, z) => x+y+z; sum(1)(2,3)`

Comment: I just wonder that what is the benefit gained from this kind of pattern.